# How do I create a fraction class with two friend functions in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an assignment that requires alot of use with classes, the idea of the code is to manipulate fractions to find greatest common denominator (GCD) and other things.

What I need (I know this is long):
Create a Fraction class with 2 private member variables numerator and denominator....one constructor with 2 integer parameters num and den with default values 0 and 1......one display function that prints out a fraction in the format numerator/denominator in the proper form such as 2/3 or 1/2. (2/4 for example should be displayed as 1/2)

HINTS FROM PROFESSOR:

1. Add a public membeer function called void proper().... that sets numerator and denomonator to the proper form by dividing both by the GCD(greatest common denominator) of them (example... you declare 12/18... after calling proper()...it becomes 2/3 (as the GCD of these is 6)
2. use public member function GCD() to get the greatest common denominator of the numerator and demoniator...(example 2/4... GCD() returns 2....for 12/18...GCD() returns 6).

[b]Code provided for GCD()

```
 int GCD()
{
int gcd = 0;
int r=0;
u = numerator;
v = denominator;
while (true) {
if (v==0){
gcd = u;
break;
}
else {
r = u%v;
u =v;
v=r;
}
}
return gcd;
}
```

THEN

Create 2 functions as FRIEND functions of class fraction.

The first one called "sum" takes 2 fraction objects as parameters, it returns a fraction object with the result of the sum of the 2 fraction objects.(example... suppose a=1/4...b=1/2... the result of sum(a,b) should be 3/4.

The second one called "compare"...takes 2 fraction objects as parameters.... it returns 1 if the 2 are equal... and 0 if not. (example....a=1/2...b=2/4.. the result of compare(a,b) is 1)

Write main function to declare fraction objects and demonstrate a working code.
[/b]

So thats what im looking at... here is what I have so far... I know its not very much...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction

{

void friend sum();

void friend compare ();

private:

int numerator;

int denominator;

public:

fraction(int num = 0, int den = 1);

int GCD();

void proper();



void fraction::proper()

{

}

int GCD()

{

int gcd = 0;

int r=0;

u = numerator;

v = denominator;

while (true) {

if (v==0){

gcd = u;

}


else {

r = u%v;

u =v;

}

}

return gcd;

}

void sum()

{

}

void compare()
{
}
void main()
{





}
```

I am VERY confused about how to set this up with a "1/2" type input... im use to simple inputs like 1 or 2. If someone could help fill in the gaps a bit I would appreciate it... (keep in mind Im a beginner..)... this is my first time working with anything like this and I am in way over my head

Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code with a consistent indentation. VC++ has a tool that can do it automatically for you. Then, remove everything that isn't really necessary for your question, so you and people here can focus on just the part that gives you problems. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you were given two fractions, one in the form `p/q` and the other in the form `x/y` (where `p`, `q`, `x`, and `y` are all integers) how would you produce their sum on paper?   Similarly, if you were given a vulgar fraction in the form `x/y` and also given a value `g` that is the greatest common divisor of `x` and `y`, how would you simplify (again on paper) that fraction?   In short, if you can't describe how YOU would do such calculations, you can't expect to write code to do it (since code is a means to describe, to the computer (or to the compiler in C++)  how to do the calculation).

Comment: `void main()` don't use this, even if it works with VC++. Other C++ compilers won't accept `main` functions with a return type other than `int` and VC++ accepts `int main()` too, so always go with that; it's one less change you need to apply to make your code work with other C++ compilers

Comment: Sorry Ulrich but I don't understand what you mean by formatting my code with consistent indentation.

Comment: Obviously the GCD section has been completed by the prof... but I wasnt sure how to use it in the other areas... like I said Im not too great at this stuff.
void fraction::proper() // needs to use GCD to change a variable... so for example.. the user inputs 15 and 20.... then it will run that through GCD... and in turn give a greatest common denominator of 5... and Proper() would produce 3/4. But Im really not sure how to write that.
I am very confused